# Assigning a variable to a "return" value of a function in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I know that functions in prolog don't "return" a value and moreover, functions don't exist (?), but instead we have predicates. However, I'm trying to write code to use Newton's method to find roots of a real-valued function. My code looks something like this:

```
newton(0,_).
newton(N,X) :-
    N > 0,
    write(X), nl,
    Y is f(X),
    Y_prime is f_prime(X),
    X_new is X - ((Y)/(Y_prime)),
    S is N-1,
    newton(S,X_new).
```

By simply writing, for example, `3*(X*X*X)-6*X+3` instead of `f(X)` and `6*(X*X)-6` instead of `f_prime(X)` we get a code that works perfectly when calling something like:

```
newton(10, 2).
```

However I would like to add some kind of previous statements (or predicates) like:

```
f(X,Y):-
    Y is 3*(X*X*X) - (X*X) + 6.
f_prime(X,Y):-
    Y is 6*(X*X) - 2*X.
```

And use these to somehow assign a value to `Y` and `Y_prime` in the main `newton` predicate. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you do with querying newton(N,X)

```
newton(0,_).
newton(N,X) :-
    N > 0,
    write(X), nl,
    f(X, Y),                      % <--
    f_prime(X, Y_prime),          % <--
    X_new is X - ((Y)/(Y_prime)),
    S is N-1,
    newton(S,X_new).
```

Comment: Thank you! Coming from an imperative perspective, it seems a little out there that simply by calling f(X,Y), the "variables" Y and Y_prime are assigned a value without explicitly telling Prolog to do so.

Comment: @D.Brito well that's partly why we say "functions don't exist (?)". It's not really calling a function, it's more like a template for Prolog to fill in the unknown variables wherever they are. The dream is that you can leave any, or all, variables blank and have Prolog find values for them, that's why there's no input/output/return variable, they're all equal. Reality is a lot more limited in what it can and cannot solve, but that's what the ideal case is.